# How send 2 entity in json for rest

Tags: json, jax-rs

I am trying do this:
 `@POST @Path("/add") @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) void addStudentInCourse(DtoCourse course, DtoStudent student);`
But this do not work:
`PUT http://localhost:8080/university/api/v1/study/
Content-Type: application/json

{
"course": {
"id": 1
},
"student": {
"id": 5
}
}`
how i can sand 2 entity in my json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send two objects like the way you want because the whole body of your request is an object, therefore, you should created a "wrapping object" which has both desired params.
Having this in mind, my suggestion is to create a request dto to encompass your objects, as per the code below:

```
public class AddStudentInCourseRequest {

  private DtoCourse course;
  private DtoStudent student;

  // constructor, getters and setters
}
```

And change the signature of your service to:

```
@POST 
@Path("/add") 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
void addStudentInCourse(AddStudentInCourseRequest request) {
  DtoCourse course = request.getCourse();
  DtoStudent student = request.getStudent();

  // remaining business logic
}
```

This way, the request you want to send should work:

```
{ 
  "course": { "id": 1 }, 
  "student": { "id": 5 } 
}`
```

Ps.: Just double check the http method. In your request, you are using PUT and in your method you are using the @POST annotation